# Dimension formula for a semisimple lie group

Tags: lie-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

The attached picture is from Hitchin's Duke paper STABLE BUNDLES AND INTEGRABLE SYSTEMS.
Let G be a semsimple complex Lie group and $P_1,P_2...P_k$ be a basis of homogeneous invariant polynomials in the ring of invariant polynomials of degree $d_i$ respectively. Then Hitchin claims the following is well known.
Can someone give a proof of this?

[image]

Comment: In the paper you've quoted, Hitchin goes on to give two ways to prove it and a source for each one in the following paragraph. You can either take a series of $2d_i -1$ forms as a basis for the cohomology or split $\mathfrak{g}$ into $2d_i -1$-dimensional submodules for the action of an appropriate principal $SL_2$ (or maybe $PSL_2$)